# Under what conditions does $f$ belong to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$. Set
$$
  f(x)=\{1+|x|^{\alpha}\}^{-1}\{1+|\log |x||^{\beta}\}^{-1}, \quad x\in\mathbb{R}^N.
$$
Under what conditions does $f$ belong to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

Thank you!

Comment: Using polar coordinates to reduce the integral to a one dimensional improper integral might help? So that $|x| = r$ for $r\in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you! Using polar coordinates, we can get$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|f(x)|^pdx=\omega_n\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{r^{N-1}}{(1+r^{\alpha})^p(1+|\log r|^{\beta})^p}dr$. How to get the condtions from the latter integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only have to see how $f$ behaves for |x| near $+\infty$, in this case $$ f(x)^{\:p} \sim \dfrac{1}{|x|^{\alpha \: p}|\log |x||^{\beta \: p}},$$  so $f^p$ is convergent according to $L^1$ either for $\alpha > 1/p$ with no condition on $\beta$, or when $\alpha=1/p$ and $\beta>1/p.$

Comment: The answer I gave is for $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, you have to adapt it to $L^1(\mathbb{R^N}).$

Comment: Note $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|f(x)|^pdx=\omega_n\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{r^{N-1}}{(1+r^{‌​\alpha})^p(1+|\log r|^{\beta})^p}dr$, and $\frac{r^{N-1}}{(1+r^{‌​\alpha})^p(1+|\log r|^{\beta})^p}\thicksim \frac{1}{r^{\alpha p-N+1}|\log r|^{\beta p}}$, so either for $\alpha>N/p$ and $\forall \beta$, or $\alpha=N/p$ and $\beta>1/p$ $|f|^p$ is convergent. Was my computing correct? Thank you!

Comment: @liuwul000, yes!