# Brezis Exercise 4.1: Find conditions for a function to be in Lp

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, alternative-proof

I am stuck on showing the following exercise on Brezis, I am aware of this answer ([Under what conditions does $f$ belong to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866703/under-what-conditions-does-f-belong-to-lp-mathbbrn)), but I would like to see a more detailed explanation. In particular, I am not sure how to make the notion "$\sim$" rigorous:

> Let $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta > 0$. Set
> $$
> f(x) = \frac{1}{1 +|x|^\alpha} \frac{1}{1 + |\log|x||^\beta}, x \in \mathbb{R}^N.
> $$
> Under what conditions does $f$ belong to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

**Here is my attempt so far:** We wish to find conditions such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{1}{(1 + |x|^\alpha)^p}\ \frac{1}{(1 + |\log|x||^\beta)^p} \,dx < \infty.
$$
We have by changing to spherical coordinate that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{1}{(1 + |x|^\alpha)^p}\ \frac{1}{(1 + |\log|x||^\beta)^p} \,dx < \infty \iff \int_{0} ^\infty \frac{1}{(1 + r^\alpha)^p} \frac{1}{(1 + |\log r|^\beta)^p} r^{N - 1} \,dr < \infty
\end{align*}
Now noticing that when $r$ is small, we have the integrand to be extremly small, so we can wrote the integral as
\begin{align*}
\int_{0} ^\infty \frac{1}{(1 + r^\alpha)^p} \frac{1}{(1 + |\log r|^\beta)^p} r^{N - 1} \,dr &= \int_0 ^1 \frac{r^{N - 1}}{(1 + r^\alpha)^p} \frac{1}{(1 + |\log r|^\beta)^p} \,dr + \int_1 ^\infty \frac{r^{N - 1}}{(1 + r^\alpha)^p} \frac{1}{(1 + |\log r|^\beta)^p} \,dr
\end{align*}
For the first integral, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0 ^1 \frac{r^{N - 1}}{(1 + r^\alpha)^p} \frac{1}{(1 + |\log r|^\beta)^p} \,dr \leq \int_0 ^1 \frac{r^{N - 1}}{(1 + r^\alpha)^p} \,dr \leq \int_0 ^1 \frac{r^{N - 1}}{r^{\alpha p}} \,dr = \int_0 ^1 r^{N - 1 - \alpha p} \,dr = \frac{r^{N - \alpha p}}{N - \alpha p}
\end{align*}
Now the quantity is finite as long as $N - \alpha p > 0$. I wish to do a similar thing for the second integral, but getting rid of $\frac{1}{(1 + r^\alpha)^p}$. However, this will make the integral to blow up. I am stuck at this point. Especially I have not found a way to get a condition relating to $\beta$.

Comment: For $r\in (0,1)$ you can estimate the integrand from above by $r^{N-1}$, which is bounded. For $r>1$ estimate the integrand from above by $r^{N-1} / r^{\alpha p}( \log r)^{\beta p}$

Comment: Another way to solve the 'if and only if' condition at once is to split the integral into integrals over regions defined by $n \le |x| < n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

We want to know if the first integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{1}{(1 + |x|^\alpha)^p}\ \frac{1}{(1 + |\log|x||^\beta)^p} \,dx$ converge or not.

This is when:

- if $\alpha > \frac N p$ then for all $\beta$
- if $\alpha > \frac N p$ then for $\beta = \frac 1 p$

First remark: in your integral there are not problems in $0$ because $1+|x|^{\alpha}$ goes to $1$ and $1+|\log |x||^\beta$ goes to $+\infty$ as $x \to 0$.

Now you have to deal with the following:
$$\int_{2} ^\infty \frac{1}{(1 + r^\alpha)^p} \frac{1}{(1 + |\log r|^\beta)^p} r^{N - 1} \,dr < \infty$$
To understand the behavior of the function you might write:

$$\int_{2} ^\infty \frac{1}{(1 + r^\alpha)^p} \frac{1}{(1 + |\log r|^\beta)^p} r^{N - 1} \,dr = \int_{2} ^\infty \frac{1}{r^{\alpha p}(1 + r^{-\alpha})^p} \frac{1}{|\log r|^{\beta p}(1 + |\log r|^{-\beta})^p} r^{N - 1} \,dr = \int_{2} ^\infty \frac{1}{r^{\alpha p - N + 1} |\log r|^{\beta p}} \frac{1}{(1 + |\log r|^{-\beta})^p(1 + r^{-\alpha})^p} \,dr$$
Finally you notice that for $r \geq 2$ one has $1 \leq (1 + |\log r|^{-\beta})^p(1 + r^{-\alpha})^p \leq (1 + |\log 2|^{-\beta})^p(1 + 2^{-\alpha})^p<+\infty$
where the last term is a finite constant.

Using this $2$ inequalities you can understand the "only if" in your question.